# How to make a decimal which is a dollar amount add leading 0's to the front of the value? REPLICATE() does not add 0 and FORMAT rounds the decimal up

Tags: sql

```
--does not add 0 to the end of decimal  making the feild length 13
left(replicate('0',13) + TOTAL_HOURS_YTD, 13) --> 75.00
,left(replicate('0',13) + GROSS_PAY_YTD, 13) --> 5387.66

--adds 0 to beginning and rounds up decimal = len 13
,format(TOTAL_HOURS_YTD, '0000000000000') --> 0000000000075
,format( GROSS_PAY_YTD, '0000000000000') --0000000005388
```

I still want the . rest of the coin value

Answer (score 0):

Include the decimal placeholders with the format string:

```
format(TOTAL_HOURS_YTD, '0000000000000.00')
```

But as to the title question:

> make a decimal ... add leading 0's to the front of the value?

This is just not possible. When you add leading zeros to the front of a decimal value it *ceases to be a decimal* and instead becomes a string.

Keep in mind: once you convert values from decimal to string you can no longer do real math with them without converting them back to decimals. Really, this is work best left to the client code or reporting tool. Additionally, thanks to internationalization/cultural issues, these conversions much slower and more error-prone than you would expect; definitely something to avoid as much as possible.

Comment: I read the word "make" in the opposite sense as in "to coerce" or "to transform". I think OP is starting with a decimal value.